# How to change column type of a devExpress xtra Grid Control to CheckBox type column?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

In .net grid view Control Column we have a Property called "ColumnType" where we can specify column type which you want

[image]

Any body please help me how to do this in DevExpress Extra Grid Control

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar effect can be achieved by setting the column's ColumnEdit property to an instance of the RepositoryItemCheckEdit.  For more details, please refer to the [Assigning Editors to Columns and Card Fields](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument746) topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim checkEditColumn = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit()
checkEditColumn .CheckStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckStyles.Style1
checkEditColumn .Name = "test"
GridView1.Columns("columnName").ColumnEdit = checkEditColumn
```